# Without program changes is there any way to handle the "receiver too small to hold the result" issue

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am facing "Receiver too small to hold the result" error in a batch job and the job is going to MSGW. I need to provide a temporary solution without program changes and without the job to be ended. Is there any way to handle it?

Answer (score 3):

The program has failed, and it is ended already. It is just telling you why. You might have a retry option if the program is being called from a CLP. If that is the case, you may be able to start a SEP debugging session, and retry. This may let you fix the problem before it happens, but programming changes are necessary for a long term fix.

Comment: Before delivering a program fix , I just wanted the job to continue even after encountering the "receiver too small to hold the result" error when the next time the job encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default reply for error message to ignore (I) by using temporary message file. Check following link for example that changes default reply and overrides message file. Use CL program to change message default and call your program from new CL program after changing default. This gives you time for program fix.

https://www.code400.com/forum/forum/iseries-programming-languages/clp-clle/10003-addrpyle-to-confirm-or-ignore-warning-sql-drop-column